# Calculating Hamming Weight in O(1)

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

In binary representation, hamming weight is the number of 1's. I came across web and found an O(1) answer to it:

```
v = v - ((v>>1) & 0x55555555);
v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v>>2) & 0x33333333);
int count = ((v + (v>>4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
```

However I don't quite understand the algorithm and cannot find a description of it anywhere. Can someone please explain it a little bit especially the last line (what the heck does *0x1010101 and then >> 24 mean)?

Comment: Side-note: It isn't actually `O(1)`. It's `O(log(n))` to the number of bits whereas a straightforward loop is `O(n)`. For a fixed integer size, both this and a straight-forward loop are `O(1)`.

Comment: @Mysticial Yeah, If we consider a 32-bit int, they are both O(1). But this one should be faster than the iteration counting, right?

Comment: @NSF - yes, it's likely faster than iteration counting (although it does have a multiplication, so...), but that's not what Big-Oh analysis is about. Big-Oh refers to how quickly does runtime grow as a function of the size of the input. In Big-Oh, the linear count is O(n), and this algorithm is O(log(n)), which is indeed better asymptotically, but sometimes it might take a particular value of n for an asymptotically faster algorithm to perform better.

Comment: I'm not sure this even counts as `O(log(n))`.  It's `O(log(n))` *timewise*, yes, but it accomplishes this by requiring `O(n)` parallelization, in a way that adds up to `O(n)` total computing power (which will become obvious if you run this algorithm on an entire [large] file).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is part of a divide-and-conquer strategy for counting bits, called a "population" function. The scholarly treatment of this strategy can be found in Reingold and Nievergelt, 1977.

The idea is to first sum the bits pairwise, then 4-wise, then 8-wise and so on. For example, if you have the bits `1011`, then the first pair `10` becomes `01` because there is one bit and the second becomes `10` because `10 = 2` in binary and there are two bits in `11`. The essential fact here is that:

```
population(x) = x - (x/2) - (x/4) - (x/8) - (x/16) - ... etc.
```

The exact algorithm you have is a variant of what is known as the "HAKMEM" algorithm (see Beeler, Gosper and Schroppel, 1972). This algorithm counts `1`'s in 4-bit fields in parallel, then these sums are converted into 8-bit sums. The last step is an operation to add these 4 bytes by multiplying by `0x01010101`. The `0x0F0F0F0F` mask gets the 4-wise bytes sums by masking out non-sum information. For example, lets say the 8-wise field is `10110110`, then there are 5 bits which is equal to `0101`, thus we will have `10110101`. Only the last four bits are significant, so we mask out the first four, ie:

```
10110101 & 0x0F = 00000101
```

You can find an entire chapter on the minutiae of counting bits in the book "Hacker's Delight" by Henry Warren.